# Markov approximation at low temperatures

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, quantum-optics, correlation-functions, low-temperature-physics

I'm interested in a two-level system in contact with a reservoir of harmonic oscilators, described by the following Hamiltonian:
$$
\hat{H}=\hat{H}_S+\hat{H}_R+\hat{H}_{RS}=\hbar\omega_0\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a}+\sum_j\hbar\omega_j\hat{r}_j^\dagger\hat{r}_j+\sum_j\hbar\left(\kappa_j^*\hat{a}\hat{r}_j^\dagger+\kappa_j\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{r}_j\right),
$$
so that if $\hat{R}_0$ is the reservoir density operator
$$
\hat{R}_0=\prod_j e^{\hbar\omega_j\hat{r}_j^\dagger\hat{r}_j/k_BT}\left(1-e^{-\hbar\omega_j/k_BT}\right)
$$
one can find a correlation function for the reservoir given by
$$
C_R(\tau)=\sum_j|\kappa_j|^2e^{i\omega_j\tau}\bar{n}(\omega_j,T),
$$
with
$$
\bar{n}(\omega_j,T)=\frac{1}{e^{\hbar\omega_j/k_BT}-1}.
$$

Now, if the reservoir is made of light, by using the density of states for a QED cavity, one can find that the correlation function is
$$
C_R(\tau)\propto\int_0^\infty d\omega \omega^3 e^{i\omega\tau}\bar{n}(\omega,T)\propto\zeta_H\left(4,1-\frac{i\tau}{\beta}\right).
$$

In the bove expression, $\zeta_H(a,x)$ is the Hurwitz-zeta function, $\beta=1/T$ and I used natural units, i.e., $\hbar=c=k_B=1$.

Now, by defining a time-scale for the reservoir at $T=300$K $t_{R}=\hbar/k_B(300K)$, the real parto of correlation function (normalized to $C_R(0)$) for $T=300K$, $T=10$K, and $T=1$K looks like the following figures:

[image: Real part of the normalized correlation function]

As can be noticed, for $T=300$K the decay time of the reservor is $\tau_R^{300K}\sim t_{R}\approx0.25\times10^{-13}$s. On the other hand, for $T=10$K, $\tau_R^{10K}\sim60t_{R}\approx1.5\times10^{-12}$, and $\tau_R^{1K}\approx0.25\times10^{-10}$. The first two decay times are much less than the decay of an atom $t_s\sim 10^{-8}$s, while $t_s\sim10^{2}\tau_R^{1K}$.

**My question is**: What is the reason to say that Markov approximation is only valid at high temperatures? The above analysis (if is correct) ensures that the decay of the atom is slow compared to the decay for $T=300$K and $T=10$K (the case $T=1$K is hard to justify). Then, in both cases $\hat{\rho}(t-\tau)\approx\hat{\rho}(t)$, because $t_s\gg\tau_R^{10K}>\tau_R^{300K}$.

Is this correct? Or $T=10$K is understood as high temperature?

I will thankful for any comment/correction.